# 80% of/in the under-26s

Tags: prepositions

I don't know how to add data. Should I use **in** or **of**?

> Most people in the three youngest age brackets studied for a career,
> although the number decreased from roughly 80% **of/in** the under-26s to 55%
> **of/in** 30- to 39-year-olds.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use **of** when referring to about the individual people in an group "80% of under-25s".

You use **in** when talking about a group: "80% in the under-25 age group".

You can, of course, use both: "80% of people in the under-25 age group".

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You first used under-25s and then used **the** under-25s. Is there a typo?

Comment: That's not a typo. It's the difference between the under-25s *surveyed in this study*, and under-25s *in general*, who are theoretically represented by this study.

Comment: @Learner110 the definite article is required in the second sentence because you are talking about a **specific** group of people - those that are under 25, whereas the first sentence refers to **all** people that are under 25, so no article is required. It's like the difference between these two sentences "children these days eat too many sweets" - this relates to all children, so no article is required, and "the children in my street are very well behaved" - this relates to a specific group of children, so the definite article is required.